# Javascript Module pattern. How to access globals inside the module

Tags: javascript, module, closures

I have seen the following code

```
var MODULE = (function () {
var my = {},
    privateVariable = 1;

function privateMethod() {
    // ...
}

my.moduleProperty = 1;
my.moduleMethod = function () {
    // ...
};

return my;
 }());
```

the properties can be accessed like MODULE.moduleProperty ...right?
But how to access globals privateVariable and privateMethod() inside the module(which are globals insode the module  ...right?)

Comment: You can just use/call them directly, right?  Since they are declared within the scope of your module's closure, everything inside that closure has access to them.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok...so i cannot access them outside the closure right?...So provide privacy?

Comment: Yes, that's the point of the closure (and the module pattern).  Any variable declared within the closure is accesible in the closure but not outside of it, unless it is assigned as a property of the module object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access them from WITHIN the module code itself as such:

```
var MODULE = (function () { 
 var my = {},
 privateVariable = 1;
 function privateMethod() {
  alert('this is private!');
 }

 my.moduleProperty = 1;
 my.moduleMethod = function () {
  privateMethod();
  return privateVariable;
 };
 return my;
}());
```

Doing this:

```
MODULE.moduleMethod();
```

Will call private method (and alert 'this is private!') and return the value of privateVariable.

There is no way to access privateVariable or privateMethod outside the MODULE scope.

```
var MODULE = (function() {
 //...declare your module as above
}());

console.log(MODULE.privateVariable); //logs undefined
```

Hopefully that helps clear it up for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not global, they are local variables inside the anonymous function.

You can access them from any code within the function, but outside the function they are not directly accessible.